# Perl/regex to check for company symbols

Tags: regex, perl

I am parsing a html document.. and i am finally to the point where, i need to check for lines that might contain symbols (1 or many)

> > AAPL, GOOG, MSFT
> >     AAPL
> >     GE
> >     GE, NVDA, IBM, CRM

As you can see the lines could contain one or more symbols (delimeted by comma's).. how can i check the line to check if satisifies above criteria? (i.e. to check whether one or more symbols are in that specific line being processed)

my first stab at it - which doesnt seem to work (since the line with all the symbols are usually below 20 characters)..
`if($checkforcompanysymbol =~ m/^[a-z0-9]{0,20}$?/)`

Comment: How do you decipher a symbol from any other word?

Comment: a symbol could be 1 character (e.g. C) or upto 4 (e.g. NSWA)

Comment: For all my reasons in stema's comment, I think you should consider changing the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^[A-Z]{1,4}(?:,\s?[A-Z]{1,4})*$
```

See it [online here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uf26)

`^` match the start of the string

`[A-Z]` character class, match any char from the range A-Z

`[A-Z]{1,4}` match 1-4 characters from the character class

`(?:,\s?[A-Z]{1,4})*` `(?: ...)` is a non capturing group, `,\s?` is a comma followed by an optional whitespace, 1-4 chars and all this 0 or more times (because of the `*`).

`$` matches the end of the string

Comment: **This won't work** if you have a ***different delimiter*** type (eg `APPL-GOOG-MSFT`,`APPL | GOOG | MSFT`) or ***different case*** (eg `appl, goog, msft`) or ***no commas*** (eg `APPL GOOG MSFT`) or a ***space before delimiter*** (eg `APPL , GOOG , MSFT`) or a ***space at the beginning*** of the line (eg ` APPL, GOOG, ...`)

Comment: @vol7ron, of course you are right, this will not work with a different delimiter. **But the OP defined that the delimiter is a comma.** A small valid point is the leading space, but this would be a really simple fix to allow this.

Comment: @stema: you're right; if the user has control over input, this is perfectly valid.  The thing that worries me is the fact that he's parsing an HTML document, which I normally associate with inconsistency, especially regarding spaces.

Answer (score 1):

(1) You are using [a-z0-9] character class which is *lower case* alphabets and the digits 0-9. The company symbols are in upper case. You may want to use [A-Z0-9].

(2) Your quantifier means at least *0* times but not more than 20 times. What company name has 0 length? You may want to use {1,20} (or some other number that better characterizes company names).

(3) I'm not sure that the regex you gave is good enough to characterize company symbols? For instance, assuming you take (1) and (2) into consideration and use [A-Z0-9]{1,20} will match NOTACOMPANY, unless I'm mistaken. If it was me, I'd just have a list of all companies from which I'd check.

(4) Your regex doesn't seem to take commas into account.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `$?` is doing at the end, but you can try:

```
m/\b\w{1,4}\b/
```

or

```
m/\b[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\b/
```

---

Looks like **[it works for me](http://codepad.org/PTgY6m5i)**:

```
while (<DATA>){
   print "$..\t$_";

   my @matches = (/\b([a-zA-Z]{1,4})\b/g);     # can use \w instead of [a-zA-Z]

   if ( scalar(@matches) ){
      print "\tMatched: [" 
          , join( "\|" , @matches ) 
          , "]\n\n" 
   }
}

__DATA__
A
B
C
AAPL, GOOG, MSFT
AAPL
GE
GE, NVDA, IBM, CRM
X
Y
Z
FOOBAR    
('GE, MSFT')
```

Comment: Doesnt work, not sure why.. here's an example of a string ('GE, MSFT').. but your regex does not return true :(

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me, [see the example](http://codepad.org/vPcrBSju).  I even used your same exact string and used `FOOBAR` as a too long case

Answer (score 0):

Using a csv module might be overkill for this data set, but here's a way to do it. Added a bit of overkill sorting and counting as well, for fun:

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    allow_whitespace => 1,
});

my @list;
while (my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA)) {
    for (@$row) {
        push @list, $_ if /^\w{1,4}$/;
    }
}

my %count;
for (@list) {
    $count{$_}++;
}

for (sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} || $a cmp $b } keys %count ) {
    printf "%-6s %-3s\n", $_, $count{$_};
}

__DATA__
A
B
some random line messing regexes up
,,
C
AAPL, GOOG, MSFT
AAPL
GE
GE, NVDA, IBM, CRM
X
```

**Output:**

```
AAPL   2
GE     2
A      1
B      1
C      1
CRM    1
GOOG   1
IBM    1
MSFT   1
NVDA   1
X      1
Y      1
Z      1
```